# jQuery Switching order of two <options> with specific values

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am looking to reorder a dropdown menu using jQuery's `.insertBefore` method. I'm having some trouble with selecting each `option`'s `value` attribute, though.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4WGvB/1/

Basically, thing 1 should be placed before thing 2 using the method.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Thing 2</option>
    <option value="2">Thing 1</option>
    <option value="3">Thing 3</option>
</select>

$($(("option").attr({value: "2"})).insertBefore($(("option").attr({value: "1"})));
```

Comment: You're using the syntax for _creating_ new option elements, not for _selecting_ them.

Comment: hmm... could you show the correct way in answer format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using the .attr() method as a setter. In any case, you can never use .attr() as a SELECTOR.

Take a look at this fiddle:

```
$('option[value="2"]').insertBefore($('option[value="1"]'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4WGvB/2/

Comment: Ah! I had tried that before, must've not done it right. To insert variables, I'll just escape the quotes then, right?

Comment: Yeah, I seem to be having some trouble escaping the quotes. This seems to not be the way to do it: `$('option[value='x']').insertBefore($('option[value="1"]'));`

Comment: Use double quotes when inside a single quoted string, or vice versa.

Comment: Nevermind, you can insert a variable by doing `$('option[value=' + x + ']').insertBefore($('option[value="1"]'));`